# 2 bytes of message length Iso 8583

Tags: message, iso8583

I got the following beginning of a Iso message (in Hex)

20 80 00 00 50 F0 F8 F1 F0 F8 F2 F3 F8 F0 F0.....

And I know that this iso has 2 bytes (20 80) to calculate the message length. The result I got is 160 (Dec), but the real message length is 734. Anyone knows how to get this result?

Comment: It seems that the 2 bytes shall be concatenated, not added, so it would actually be `0x20 0x80` which is 8320 bytes : that's a lot. Are you sure about your data integrity ? 734 is `0x02 0xDE`, which have no match in your message...

Comment: I solved the problem, the 20 in the beginning means that the message has more than one block. eg.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem, the 20 in the beginning means that the message has more than one

block. eg.

the beginnig and the final part of the message is

20 80 00 00 50 F0 F8 F1 F0 F8 F2 F3 F8 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F2 F4 F1 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F4 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F2 F1 F1 F0 F3 F1 F8 F2 F6 F5 F0 F0 F2 F7 F3 F0 F0 F1 F8 F2 F6 F5 F0 F1 F1 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F5 F2 F8 F8 F9 F0 F3 F5 F2 F8 F7 F6 F7 F5 F6 F2 F4 C9 D5 C1 F0 F0 F1 F0 F3 F0 F7 F2 F0 F1 F4 F0 F1 F0 F1 F6 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F4 F0 F7 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 20 80 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 20 80 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F2 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F9 F8 F6 F0 F0 F7 F6 F0 F2 F9 F9 F0 F2 F1 F2 F0 F2 F1 F2 F0 F2 F1 F2 F0 F3 F0 F3 F0 F2 F9 F9 F0 F2 F9 F9 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 ....... 00 54 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F2 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F4 F0 F4 F0 F4 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F9 F7 F5 F3 F2 F1 F1 F9 F4 F2

so I needed to break the message in blocks of 128 bytes.

20 means that the message has another block

80 means that this block has 128 bytes

Then I got the first block

20 80 00 00 50 F0 F8 F1 F0 F8 F2 F3 F8 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F2 F4 F1 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F4 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F2 F1 F1 F0 F3 F1 F8 F2 F6 F5 F0 F0 F2 F7 F3 F0 F0 F1 F8 F2 F6 F5 F0 F1 F1 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F5 F2 F8 F8 F9 F0 F3 F5 F2 F8 F7 F6 F7 F5 F6 F2 F4 C9 D5 C1 F0 F0 F1 F0 F3 F0 F7 F2 F0 F1 F4 F0 F1 F0 F1 F6 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F4 F0 F7 F0 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0

the second block is the same

20 means that the message has another block

80 means that this block has 128 bytes

Then I got the second block

20 80 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F0 F0 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0

until the last block

00 means that the message has no more blocks

54 means that this final block has 84 bytes

then the final block is

00 54 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F2 F3 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F4 F0 F4 F0 F4 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F0 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F0 F0 F1 F0 F0 F9 F7 F5 F3 F2 F1 F1 F9 F4 F2